# OOP & PHP Runtime

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP & PHP. I've followed the OOP Approach as best I can so for each of the prominent "nouns" in my specification I have a class and this is working well.

But it got me thinking about compilation and runtime.

If I develop a comprehensive class, that has relevent properties, setters and getters and a series of methods, the resulting class could easily run into a couple of hundred lines of code.

If I then use this class, whereby (for example) I only call one method hasn't the whole class got to be parsed & converted and memory allocated before execution?

Have I got this right? As surely a procedural approach would be far more efficient (a function within an include) or is it that in real-world runtime this is negligable?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that including files containing functions doesn't require parsing and "converting" or memory allocating

Comment: No I'm not, but surely its more efficent to parse and convert one function than the whole class?

Comment: Files are parsed/etc whether they contain classes or functions.... suppose you have a file with 20 functions that you include but only call one of them.... PHP still parses the whole file, not just the function that it predicts/guesses you're going to call when you include that file

Comment: Parsing/lexing of files that contain classes is no more and no less an overhead than Parsing/lexing of files that contain procedural functions..... and if you're using OpCache, that only happens once and then the compiled bytecode is cached.... whether that's classes or procedural functions

Comment: @JAMMac: If the class file is hundreds of lines of code, why do you suspect a file of just functions would be significantly fewer lines?  Why do you suspect that the PHP engine parses function structures more efficiently than class structures?  Do you know something about the internals of PHP's language parsing logic that you're basing this on?

Comment: Have you tried a [phar](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php)?

Comment: I completely understand that an include file with 20+ functions would have to be parsed & converted in a similar manner to a class. My question was if you divided the functions into their own files (I said in the original post "a function within an include") wouldn't this be a more efficient approach as you would only be including code that you actually indended for runtime?

Comment: Unlikely nowadays.... most class based systems use an autoloader, which only includes classes/files that are actively required to handle the request..... so extremely efficient; and most modern sites use an opcache so once compiled to bytecode it's held in cache memory so doesn't need recompiling

Comment: And if you split your file with 20 functions into individual files for each function, and include only those you need, you'd just increased your "very slow" disk access significantly.... disk/file access is slow in comparison with lexing/parsing

Comment: @Mark Baker - thank you for your constructive responses, this makes sense complete sense. I thought for a minute I would have to get myself a hard hat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regard to

> But it got me thinking about compilation and runtime.

I think @Mark [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522215/oop-php-runtime/33533643#comment54826708_33522215) is most pertinent:

> most class based systems use an autoloader, which only includes classes/files that are actively required to handle the request.....

Atomic classes with single responsibilities, autoloaded from a dependency injection container would produce a low amount of unused code.

> If I then use this class, whereby (for example) I only call one method hasn't the whole class got to be parsed & converted and memory allocated before execution?

Lengthy classes can sometimes be broken into smaller classes, which limits the amount of code loaded to execute a single method. I think the key here is the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), inducing classes that will need the bare minimal resources they need to operate the function they are called to do.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that all included files are parsed, and a few hundred lines of code is not that much, but if you want you can simply think about some static helper methods for this kind of functions if it's possible.

In combination with an autoloader you could really drop mass includes.

**Example before**

One class,that you always include:

```
class Helper {
    public static function createFolder() {
        // some stuff
    }

    public static function myEncoder() {
        // some stuff
    }

    public static function getDomElementByID() {
        // some stuff
    }

    public static function cleanupString() {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

**Example afterwards:**

Split your "huge" class and try to group the methods in it.

**class StringHelper**

```
class StringHelper {
    public static function cleanupString() {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

**class FilesystemHelper**

```
class FilesystemHelper {
    public static function createFolder() {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

**class DomHelper**

```
class DomHelper {
    public static function getDomElementByID() {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

**class EncodingHelper**

```
class EncodingHelper {
    public static function myEncoder() {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

**Autoloader**

Create a autoloader class, more information here => [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

The Autoloader will only include the files when you actually need it. For example if you are calling:

```
$stringHelper = new StringHelper();
// or
StringHelper::someStaticFunction();
```

What really makes a blast to work with is the combination of namespaces and autoloader. take a look here => [PHP Docs (namespaces)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: Your `Helper` class is the exact same thing as a file with functions.

Comment: @PeeHaa, yes that's right but i suggested to split this example `Helper`class into different files, if it's possible an use an autoloader, so you don't include 2000 lines for some functions but just 200 for example.